# Area between 3 points in $\mathbb{R^3}$ space (problems with understanding why solution is wrong)

Tags: linear-algebra

We have 3 points in $\mathbb{R^3}$ space and they are defined:

$$ p_1 = (1,5,6) $$
$$ p_2 = (5,-4,1) $$
$$ p_3 = (-3,-3,-1) $$

Now these points form triangle in 3d space and i want to calculate are of this triangle. I've come up with two solutions but these two solutions give different results and i cannot understand how this is happening. Solution **(a)** appears to be correct one.

### Solution (a)

We could form two vectors defining two sides of this triangle. Lets call these vectors $u$ and $v$.

$$ u=p_1-p_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1-5 \\ 5+4 \\ 6-1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 9 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ v=p_1-p_3=\begin{bmatrix} 1+3 \\ 5+3 \\ 6+1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 8 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now with $v$ and $v$ we can define area of this "big triangle". We would get formula for area of triangle:

$$ area=\frac{|u \times v|}{2} $$
Length of cross product from $u$ and $v$ should give us area of rectangle formed by these two vectors but since we want only area of triangle we divide it by 2. Now plugging in numbers should give us our result:
$$ u{\times}v = \left|\begin{matrix}i & j & k \\ -4 & 9 & 5 \\ 4 & 8 & 7\end{matrix}\right| =(9*7-8*5)i-(-4*7-4*5)j+(-4*8-4*9)k $$
$$ 23i+8j-68k $$
$$ u \times v = \begin{bmatrix}23 \\ 48 \\-68 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ area=\frac{\sqrt{23^2+48^2+(-68)^2}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{7457}}{2} \approx 43.18$$

### Solution (b)

We could form 3 smaller triangles and then sum area of these. It's a little longer to calculate but in theory this should give us same result ?

We have 3 vectors which form 3 smaller triangles. These vectors are:

$$ u =p_1= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix}, v = p_2= \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, w = p_3=\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ -3 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

These vectors are formed by using these 3 points as vectors. Now we can form 3 cross products for each triangle:

$$ u{\times}v= \begin{bmatrix}29 \\29 \\ -29 \end{bmatrix}, v{\times}w= \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 2 \\ -27 \end{bmatrix}, w{\times}u= \begin{bmatrix} -13 \\ 17 \\ -12 \end{bmatrix}  $$

$$ area_{uv} = \frac{|u{\times}v|}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{29^2+29^2+(-29)^2}}{2}=\frac{29\sqrt{3}}{2} \approx 25.11473671$$
$$ area_{vw} = \frac{|v{\times}w|}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{7^2+2^2+(-27)^2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{782}}{2} \approx 13.98213145$$
$$ area_{wu} = \frac{|w{\times}u|}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{(-13)^2+17^2+(-12)^2}}{2}=\sqrt{301} = \approx 17.34935157$$
$$ \sum = \frac{29\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{782}}{2}+\sqrt{301} \approx 56.44621974$$

If someone could give insight here of what i am doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated. There is of course possibility that i have simply miss calculated something but i've been trying to find the mistake for few hours now and doesn't seem to be working so i'll post this here.

Thanks,

Tuki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First version is confirmed by a GeoGebra calculation:

[image]

Now I added your three vectors (the black striped arrows) and changed the view slightly:

[image]

Now it is clear why the total area increased. By using those coordinates you took the origin as starting point of those vectors, pushing the surface a bit downwards, increasing the area.

You need to use an origin (as starting point of the vectors) within the plane of the triangle.

E.g.
$$
o = (u+v+w)/3
$$
as origin (the endpoint of this vector, to be more precise) within the triangle plane and this leads to corrected vectors
$$
u' = u - o \quad\quad v' = v - o \quad\quad w' = w - o \\
P_1' = P_1 - o \quad\quad P_2' = P_2 - o \quad\quad P_3' = P_3 - o
$$

I added these as well, now it is getting crowded:

[image]

You see that the new vectors can be interpreted as going from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to the corner points $P_i'$ of a translated triangle with the same area. Or you can interpret this correction as a translation of the coordinate system.

Comment: Haha that's weird since their's a calculation mistake in his first version.

Comment: It's simply error in writing this. I have the actual notes in my notebook so i've copied them from there to here.

Comment: So this is happening because we are calculating are of plane in 3 dimensions. If we were in two dimensional space we would get exactly same area with these two methods right ? 3 small triangles dont have same area than the large one because smaller triangles are in angle compared to the large one ?

Comment: No, you just calculated your vectors wrong. You wanted something like the primed versions $u'$, $v'$, $w'$ in the first place, which lie within the triangle plane, and all go from the endpoint of vector $o$ to the corners $P_i$.  If you would redo the calculation with those vectors it would give the correct area. (You can use any other point within the plane the triangle lies in as origin as well).

Comment: @mvw would it be possible you to give example of these calculations ?

Comment: Think of your triangle as one side of the tetraeder $(0, P_1, P_2, P_3)$. The three small triangles $(O, P_1, P_2)$, $(O, P_2, P_3)$ and $(O, P_1, P_3)$ (I only listed the vertices each) you calculated were the other three faces of that tetraeder. They of course have a larger sum, than the upper triangle.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution a, the $j^{th}$ component of the cross product of $u$ with $v$, you got $-(-28-20) =8$. The 8 should be a 48 instead.

Comment: Thanks for notifying i've changed the numbers in **solution (a)** to correct ones.

Comment: Ahh I see! Sorry about that.